# Mapping Nebraska school districts with D3 v4 - base layer not showing

Tags: json, d3.js, geojson, topojson

I am having trouble mapping Nebraska school districts in D3 (v4). (See [bl.ock here](https://bl.ocks.org/arkut/13b6fa6b67a7e320194bec44c544d894).) I can map Nebraska counties no problem, but the same code modified for school districts--and pointing to a school district TopoJSON file--gives me a blank page.

Here's how I created the JSON, based on [Mike Bostock's excellent instructions](https://medium.com/@mbostock/command-line-cartography-part-1-897aa8f8ca2c) :

```
curl "https://www2.census.gov/geo/tiger/GENZ2017/shp/cb_2017_31_unsd_500k.zip" -o cb_2017_31_unsd_500k.zip

unzip -o cb_2017_31_unsd_500k.zip
shp2json cb_2017_31_unsd_500k.shp -o ne_district.json
ndjson-split "d.features" < ne_district.json > ne_district.ndjson
ndjson-map "d.id = d.properties.GEOID, d" < ne_district.ndjson > ne_district-id.ndjson
geo2topo -n districts=ne_district-id.ndjson > ne_district-id-topo.json
```

And here's my projection:

```
var projection = d3.geoConicConformal()
   .parallels([40, 43])
   .rotate([100, 0])
   .scale(8000);
```

Thanks for your help and apologies in advance for anything important I left out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is you haven't finished setting your projection parameters. You have rotate the map, which is how you should center a conic projection along the x axis. But you haven't centered the map on the y axis, it is centered on the equator. You

For a conical projection, you can do this one of three ways:

- Center the map on a central latitude : `projection.center([0,y])`

*You don't need to use .center with an x value because the map is already centered on the x by rotation, rotation and centering are cumulative*

- Rotate the map to a central latitude and longitude: `projection.rotate([-x,-y])`

*On a conical projection the rotation on the meridian does not warp the map (generally), we rotate  by the negative as we move the earth under us. This option does slightly distort the map relative to the other options - this may be preferrable.*

- Use the projection translation to center the map

The easiest way is to translate the result while automatically scaling (though you can do this manually too) with `projection.fitSize` or `projection.fitExtent`. These methods modify projection.scale and projection.translate. As with centering with .center,  you need to keep your rotation - otherwise you'll get an odd tilt to the map. 
These methods set translate and scale to appropriate values so that your map area contains the desired features:

```
var featureCollection = topojson.feature(ne, ne.objects.districts);
projection.fitSize([width,height],featureCollection);
```

*These methods must take objects, not arrays, so we use the featureCollection, not the features as an array*

Both methods take an array specifying the size to stretch a provided geojson object over:

```
projection.fitSize([mapwidth,mapheight],geojsonObject)
projection.fitExtent([[left,top],[right,bottom]],geojsonObject)
```

Here's an [updated](https://bl.ocks.org/Andrew-Reid/eac96498a3845acef6c9c7f19178e3c9) gist using fitSize.

Comment: Thank you so much -- this makes total sense, and works perfectly!